# AngularJS - $http GET response is always [object Object]

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I am just trying to fetch an array of key value pairs from PHP and send the response back to AngularJS $http GET request:

PHP Code get_projects.php file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = [{"id" => 1, "name" => 'Audi'}, {"id" => 2, "name" => 'BMW'}, {"id" => 3, "name" => 'Honda'}];
$encode = json_encode($data);
echo $encode;
?>
```

AngularJS Controller code:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name = 'Search';
    $scope.projects = '';
     $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'includes/get_projects.php',
            params: {}
         }).then(function success(response) {
            $scope.projects = response.data;
            alert($scope.projects);
     });
}]);
```

The `alert($scope.projects);` always returns `[object Object]`. The `echo gettype($encode);` prints `string` but the alert statement prints `[object Object]`. I have tried `angular.fromJson()` but still it prints `[object Object]`.

I am really confused with the concept of json_encode() function in PHP. Please help me fix the problem.

Comment: why are you using alert to debug, it is not 1990? Use `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

You converted the PHP array to a string by serializing it using JSON. `$encode` therefore is a string, which is fine.

Your frontend now gets the response and (since it came with the content type of `application/json`) already deserialized it for you from a JSON string to a JavaScript object.

Attempting to convert an object to a string will give you something like `[object Object]`. `alert` isn't the right tool here since it can work with a string only.

Try `console.log` instead and check your devtools console output, there you'll see an explorable object. (Even better: In your devtools debugger, set a breakpoint in the success handler and inspect the object at that point.)

Bottom line: It's all working fine, you just didn't use the right method to look at your object.

Comment: In the console.log output, i am able to see only `{id: 3, name: 'Honda'}`

Comment: Yes, this is correct/expected. You created an object with three duplicate keys, overwriting each other (`['a' => 1, 'a' => 2]` is the same as just `['a' => 2]`). Maybe you intended to crested an array of arrays in PHP? `[['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Audi'], ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'BMW'], ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Honda']]`

Comment: I don't think i used a duplicate key.

Comment: You did, both they keys `id` and `name` exist three times in a single array.

Comment: ok, got it. I actually wanted the array elements set as `$data = [{"id" => 1, "name" => 'Audi'}, {"id" => 2, "name" => 'BMW'}, {"id" => 3, "name" => 'Honda'}];`

Answer (score 0):

@CherryDT I think i fixed the problem.

```
     var make = [];
       for (var key in response.data) {
          if(response.data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
             make.push({
               "id": response.data[key].id,
               "name": response.data[key].name
             });
          }
        }
       $scope.projects = JSON.stringify(make);
       $scope.projects = angular.fromJson($scope.projects);
```

1. PHP send the array as string with json_encode.
2. AngularJS response.data takes the response as Object.
3. Loop through the response.data object and push the key/values to variable make.
4. Create a string with `JSON.stringify`.
5. Convert the JSON string to Object using `angular.fromJson`.

I have viewed couple of blogs which assign the `response.data` object directly to $scope variable but in my case it did not work.

AngularJS version i am using is : AngularJS v1.2.8

Comment: I don't understand why you do all these complicated things which have the same output as they have input... Twice... `$scope.projects = response.data` should be all you need, can you explain what "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: When the json string is received by AngularJS in $http response, it prints Array in console.log and for some reason the json string format returned by php is not matching the required format therefore i created a array variable and pushed all the elements enclosed in {},used stringify and angular fromJSON.

Comment: But you build a new array that has the exact same contents... And then you additionally convert it to JSON and back once more... It doesn't make any sense (or difference). What do you mean by "it's not matching the required format"? Please show it exactly, what do you get, what do you expect, in what way does it fail, etc

Comment: I replaced the static array key/value pairs with dynamic array fetched from SQL server database. I am returning the array with json_encode function. `print_r` on the array variable after json_encode was throwing an error as "Array to string conversion". As you said in the above post, i just tried sending the `json_encode($elements);` as response to angularJS and it received it without the extra javaScript work i wrote in the answer section above. This question is not required and i am unable to delete it. Thanks for the analysis as it gave me better understanding on javaScript JSON.